# r2dbc batch insert issues with connection pool

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, r2dbc

A Web-client calls a get-all endpoint which opens a Flux of articles (small object, with only 5 primitive fields) from a Postgres DB (r2dbc). See the next two code snippets.

Then I try to batch-insert a 1000 articles per batch by using a connection pool. But attempts have problems

The first code-block runs and persists, BUT ONLY ONES! After running a single batch-insert 0f 1000 it calls "completed" and runs no more, why?

The second block was remodelled after an example, it runs multiple times but and inserts (very fast) a 250.000 articles but than it crashes with the following error:

**io.netty.channel.StacklessClosedChannelException: null
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.close(ChannelPromise)(Unknown Source) ~[netty-transport-4.1.85.Final.jar:4.1.85.Final]**

[link to pool-connection example](https://github.com/r2dbc/r2dbc-pool)

**The code that delivers the article flux**

```
public Disposable copyToDestinyInBatches(Long backPressure) {

        Flux<ArticleDestiny> articleFlux = client.get()
                .uri("/article-batch-stream-from-origin/" + backPressure)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_NDJSON) //APPLICATION_NDJSON TEXT_EVENT_STREAM
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(ArticleDestiny.class)
                .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
                .doOnError(error -> log.error("Error client on batches " +
                        "message={} | error={}", error.getMessage(), error.getStackTrace()));

    return streamService.articleDestinyBatchStreamZipWith(articleFlux, backPressure);
}

public Flux<ArticleOrigin> getAllArticleStreamFromOrigin(Long backPressure) {
    return articleOriginRepo
            .findAll()
            .doOnError(e -> log.error("error get all articles message={} | error={}", e.getMessage(), e.getStackTrace()))
            .doOnNext(a -> log.debug("at stream service article id={}", a.getId()));
}
```

Find next the two batch inserts

**first:**

```
 public Disposable articleDestinyBatchStreamConnPool(Flux<ArticleDestiny> articleFlux, Long backPressure) {
    Flux<List<ArticleDestiny>> articleFluxList = articleFlux
            .bufferTimeout(backPressure.intValue(), Duration.ofMillis(1000))
            .doOnNext(a -> log.info("article batch size={} | batch-count={}", a.size(), batchCounter));
    Flux<Connection> connectionFlux = Flux.from(connectionPool.create());

    var conPoolArticleZipResult =  connectionFlux.zipWith(articleFluxList, (conPool, artList) -> {
        Batch batch = conPool.createBatch();
        artList.forEach(article -> {
            String sql = String.format("INSERT INTO article_destiny (country_code,art_number, name, price) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s')",
                    article.getCountryCode(),
                    article.getArtNumber(),
                    article.getName(),
                    article.getPrice());
            batch.add(sql);
        });
        log.debug("print each batch={}", batch);
        batchCounter++;
        return Mono
                .from(batch.execute())
                .doFinally((st -> {
                    conPool.close();
                    log.info("connection closed ");
                }));
    });
    return conPoolArticleZipResult.subscribe( //.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newParallel("process", 4))
            s -> log.info("subscribe={}", s.toString()),
            e -> log.error("error at subscribe pool-stream-service message={} | error={} | stacktrace={}",
                    e.getMessage(), e, e.getStackTrace()),
            () -> {
                log.info("completed! ");
            });
}
```

**second:**

```
public Disposable articleDestinyBatchStreamConnPool(Flux<ArticleDestiny> articleFlux, Long backPressure) {
    Flux<List<ArticleDestiny>> fluxArticleList = articleFlux
            .bufferTimeout(backPressure.intValue(), Duration.ofMillis(1000))
            .doOnNext(a -> log.info("article batch size={}", a.size()));

    Mono<Object> resultMono = Mono.usingWhen(connectionPool.create(), // allocates a connection from the pool
            connection -> {
                Batch batch = connection.createBatch();
                return fluxArticleList.flatMap(articles -> {
                    articles.forEach(article -> {
                        String sql = String.format("INSERT INTO article_destiny (country_code, art_number, name, price) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s')",
                                article.getCountryCode(),
                                article.getArtNumber(),
                                article.getName(),
                                article.getPrice());
                        batch.add(sql);
                    });
                    log.debug("print each batch={}", batch);

                    return Mono.from(batch.execute());
                }).then();
            }, Connection::close); // releases the connection back to the pool

    return resultMono.mergeWith(fluxArticleList)
            //.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newParallel("process", 4))
            .subscribe(
            s -> log.debug("subscribe={}", s.toString()),
            e -> log.error("error at subscribe pool-stream-service message={} | error={} | stacktrace={}",
                    e.getMessage(), e, e.getStackTrace()),
            () -> {
                log.info("completed! ");
                // application shutdown
                connectionPool.dispose();
                log.info("conn dispose! ");
                // here I stop the Springboot manually
            });
}
```

**Finally some programmatic config info**

First: I extends AbstractR2dbcConfiguration

Second I exclude R2dbcDataAutoConfiguration, R2dbcAutoConfiguration

**The config methods of the config class**

```
  @Bean
@Primary
@Override
public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {

    return new PostgresqlConnectionFactory(PostgresqlConnectionConfiguration.builder()
            .host("localhost")
            .port(5677)
            .username("admin")
            .password("secret")
            .database("article_flux_db")
            .tcpKeepAlive(true)
            .connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
            .statementTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10))



@Bean
public ConnectionPool connectionPool() {
    ConnectionPoolConfiguration configuration = ConnectionPoolConfiguration.builder(connectionFactory())
            .maxIdleTime(Duration.ofMillis(1000))
            .maxSize(20)
            .build();
    ConnectionPool pool = new ConnectionPool(configuration);
    return pool;
}


@Bean
public WebClient webClient() {
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create()
            .keepAlive(true)
            .responseTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(60l))
            .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 100000)
            .doOnConnected(conn -> conn
                .addHandlerLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(100)));

    WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()

    return webClient;
}

@Bean
public ConnectionFactoryInitializer initialize(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    var initializer = new ConnectionFactoryInitializer();
    initializer.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    CompositeDatabasePopulator populator = new CompositeDatabasePopulator();
    populator.addPopulators(
            new ResourceDatabasePopulator(new ClassPathResource("/db-config/schema.sql"))
    );
    initializer.setDatabasePopulator(populator);
    return initializer;
}
```